How do I mount an encrytped zfs filesystem that exists inside a full disk image?
Or if not otherwise possible, how can I get those files?
I have an image of an entire disk, made with gnome-disks. When I mount it, I see there are my 4 partitions, two of them are zfs. bpool and rpool. /dev/loop26p4 is where the rpool partition is mounted now as read only. p4 = partiton 4.
With some trail and error, I figured out how to import the rpool.
sudo zpool import -o readonly=on -f rpool I needed both the readonly and the force flags.
But now I am stuck. sudo zfs mount -o ro rpool gives
cannot mount 'rpool': 'canmount' property is set to 'off'

Because everything is read only, it seems I can not switch this on. I read that this is only for automatic mounting, but I am doing manual mounting.
I search around and based on what I found something about creating a cache file but I can not set that either because if readonly.
sudo zpool set cachefile=/tmp/zfs.cache rpool
cannot set property for 'rpool': pool is read-only

zpool status rpool
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported and requested features are not enabled on the pool.
    The pool can still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
    the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
    the features. See zpool-features(7) for details.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:07:06 with 0 errors on Sun Jun  9 00:31:07 2024
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
      1111111-2222-4444-77777-888888888888  ONLINE       0     0     0

It's also encrypted, not sure if it would just ask me for the password, I already read something about mounting zfs with encryption from command line. I am assuming this has nothing to do with it, and I am just not there yet.
My only idea would be to actually write the image back to the SSD it made from, but I already have another system installed, it would be a lot of hassle.

No, it's NOT similar, that question deals with a real file-system and not an image and therefore does not have any of the readonly issues.

$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/loop26p4 ? as in udisksctl mount -b /dev/blockdevice ? - note: I am guessing, have no clue nor experience. Add -o readonly (syntax?) ?
